# In Eclipse activity layout view, the minimum available width specified by h<N>dp auto-chooses to wrong layout folder. A bug?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, adt

I am using eclipse with the ADT.

For the activity I am using portrait view only and thus want to use the `h<N>dp` xml qualifier to specify a minimum available height for the layout.

When I name my folder `layout-h641dp` and choose the Galaxy Nexus (`640 x 360 dp`) device from the drop-down then Eclipse auto-chooses the lower `layout-h450dp` as expected.

When I rename the folder to `layout-h640dp` then I can view the layout with the Galaxy Nexus, *but it shouldn't* since the *available* height is only `519dp` plus `48dp` (for the action bar) = `567dp` (see the image) and google states at [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) that

> Note: The sizes that you specify using these qualifiers are **not the actual screen sizes**. Rather, the sizes are for the width or height in dp units that are **available to your activity's window**.

and

> Also beware that the `Action Bar` is considered a part of your application's window space, although your layout does not declare it, so it reduces the space available for your layout and you must account for it in your design.

I am thus not allowed by Eclipse to design on the correct layout that will actually be chosen by the physical device.

When actually testing on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (also `640 x 360 dp`) using `layout-h616dp` the Android system uses the lower `layout-h450dp` layout, which is correct according to the Google docs, and when I then rename the `layout-h616dp` to `layout-h615dp` the Android system chooses `layout-h615dp` for rendering which is as expected, since the available space is about `640dp` (total) minus `25dp` (for the status bar) = `615dp`.

My question: Is this a bug in Eclipse and if so, is there a workaround so that it is possible to design properly on the correct layout?

[image: Layout as on Eclipse]

**EDIT**: To clarify, in a nutshell, Eclipse uses the total screen `dp` whereas when actually running the app the Android system uses only the available 'dp' (as it should).

Comment: minimum available height... so, it's the height in landscape mode: 360.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but you have to subtract the status bar height of about 25dp so the available height in landscape is 360dp - 25dp.